# Dibujar gráfica/tabla correctamente con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de tabla que marca horarios, para ello empleo la librería `matplotlib`. Mi `input` es el siguiente:

```
input_files =[[[1,8,'P1','A1'],[2,9,'P2','A3']],
         [[1,8,'P1','A1'],[2,9,'P3','A2']]
        ]
```

Donde el primer valor es la posición, el segundo la hora y los otros dos información extra. Mi idea es que la posición 1 siempre sean las 7:00 de la mañana, el 2 las 8:00 y así sucesivamente, pudiendo llegar hasta las 14:00 que sería la posición 8.

El problema es que se me dibuja de la siguiente manera,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir me está dibujando por filas y no por columnas, pues ese verde debería estar debajo del rosa y ser rosa también, (siendo el color lo menos importante).
Yo lo que busco es que hasta las 14:00 (pos = 8) no pase a la siguiente columna.

NOTA: Veis que hay 2 conjuntos de listas en el `input`, esto es porque se generan varios horarios/tablas, pero el problema es común en todas. La imagen es de una sola de ellas.

A continuación muestro mi código,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dias_etiqueta=['Lunes','Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes']
colores=['pink', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'wheat', 'salmon']
xnm=['X1','X2']

input_files =[[[1,8,'P1','A1'],[2,9,'P2','A3']],
             [[1,8,'P1','A1'],[2,9,'P3','A2']]
            ]

for input_file, xn in zip(input_files, xnm):
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

    for data in input_file:        
        slot, inicio, profe, asignatura = data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]
        final = inicio + 1

        # plot event.
        plt.fill_between([slot, slot+1], [inicio, inicio], [final,final], color=colores[int(data[0]-1)], edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.5)

        # plot event name.
        plt.text(slot+0.5, (inicio+final)*0.5, (profe+'\n'+asignatura), ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11)

    # Set Left Axis
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.yaxis.grid()
    ax.set_xlim(0.5,len(dias_etiqueta)+0.5)
    ax.set_ylim(16, 7)
    ax.set_xticks(range(1,len(dias_etiqueta)+1))
    ax.set_xticklabels(dias_etiqueta)
    ax.set_ylabel('Hora')

    # Set Rigth Axis
    ax2=ax.twiny().twinx()
    ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
    ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
    ax2.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
    ax2.set_xticklabels(dias_etiqueta)
    ax2.set_ylabel('Hora')

    plt.title(xn,y=1)
```

Pienso que el error esté o en la manera de hacer el `for` o en esta línea, `plt.fill_between([slot, slot+1], [inicio, inicio], [final,final], color=colores[int(data[0]-1)], edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.5)` pero no consigo corregirlo. ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede introducir una variable para el día e incrementarlo cada vez se detecta que hay que empezar el siguiente día. Desafortunadamente, el formato de input no permita otra manera para saber si hay que empezar otro día.

Algunas otras ideas para cambiar el código:

- `ax.twinx` no es necesario para tener la misma eje copiada de abajo hasta arriba. Es suficiente con `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=True, labeltop=True)` para tener las etiquetas en ambos lados. Similar para izquierda y derecha.
- `ax.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False, top=False)` sirve para quitar las líneas de los ticks.
- Se puede escoger los colores de [un set ya preparado en matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html). Estos colores ya están investigado para ir bien conjunto. Por ejemplo `plt.cm.Set2.colors`.
- Una idea es emplear el alpha para ver mejor las líneas horizontales. Por emplo alternando entre `alpha=1` y `alpha=0.8`.
- Representar el eje `y` internamente en minutos permite slots que no empiezan a una hora exacta.
- ...

Por ejemplo:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

HORA = 60   # para convertir horas a una representación interna de minutos

dias_etiqueta = ['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes']
NUM_DIAS = len(dias_etiqueta)
#colores = ['pink', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'wheat', 'salmon']
colores = plt.cm.Set2.colors # https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html
xnm=['X1','X2']

input_files = [[[1,8,'P1','A1'],[2,9,'P2','A3']],
               [[1,8,'P1','A1'],[2,9,'P3','A2']]
              ]
input_files = [[[s % 7 + 1, s % 7 + 7, f'Profe_{s % 7 + 1}', f'Asignatura_{s % 7 + 1}'] for s in range(7 * NUM_DIAS)]
               for clase in range(2)]

for input_file, xn in zip(input_files, xnm):
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)  # antes de llamar plt.fill_between

    dia = 0
    inicio_anterior = 0

    for data in input_file:
        #slot, inicio, profe, asignatura = data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]
        slot, inicio, profe, asignatura = data
        final = inicio+1
        if inicio <= inicio_anterior: # mueve el dia
            dia += 1

        plt.fill_between([dia-0.5, dia+0.5], [inicio*HORA, inicio*HORA], [final*HORA, final*HORA],
                         color=colores[dia], edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.5, alpha=1 if slot % 2 != 0 else 0.8)
        plt.text(dia, (inicio+final)*HORA*0.5, (profe+'\n'+asignatura), ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11)
        inicio_anterior = inicio

    # Set Left Axis
    ax.yaxis.grid()
    #ax.set_xlim(0.5,len(dias_etiqueta)+0.5)
    ax.set_ylim(14*HORA, 7*HORA)
    ax.set_xlim(-0.5, len(dias_etiqueta) - 0.5)
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(dias_etiqueta)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(dias_etiqueta)
    # ax.set_ylabel('Hora')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=True, labeltop=True)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', left=True, right=True, labelleft=True, labelright=True)

    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(base=60)) # ticks mayores: en horas
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(base=5))  # ticks menores: cada 5 minutos
    ax.set_yticklabels(f'{int(t)//60}:{int(t)%60:02d}' for t in ax.get_yticks())

    plt.title(xn, y=1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("Horario_" + xn + ".png")
    plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo del plot]

Comment: ¿Ha sido útil esta respuesta?